# Button.BackColor is not working?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, colors

I'm trying to change the BackColor of a button during a hover event but it doesn't seem to change the BackColor at all?

It is changing the ForeColor and BorderColor but the BackColor remains the same, below is the code I've tried:

```
    private void btnTest_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnTest.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
        btnTest.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        btnTest.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.White;
    }
```

The strange thing is, if I add some of the other buttons as below, the btnSave and btnClose BackColors do actually take affect.

```
private void btnTest_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnTest.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
        btnTest.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        btnTest.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.White;

        btnSave.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
        btnSave.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        btnSave.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.White;

        btnClose.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
        btnClose.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        btnClose.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.White;

    }
```

Has anyone had this before and is there a way around this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try doing a btnSave MouseHoves and changing the btnTest backcolor. Maybe because its being hovered over it wont allow a change?

Comment: MouseHover works for me.  Hover has a delayed reaction.  Did you mean MouseEnter?  Also, make sure the FlatStyle = Flat;

Comment: ask your frined, the debugger, if the code does actually get hit!

Comment: I'll have a look and try on a fresh file also, it does change the colour from another button (but does the same if I apply the code to another button (changes anything but the button i'm hovering over)) and I'd also stepped through the code and it hit it (and assigned the BackColor) but just didn't show it on screen.  The buttons are all set to a Flat style (i'll check my Flat Appearance properties though and see if it's something i've done in there!!)

Answer (score 0):

So...I appear to have resolved the issue now

I was playing about with the FlatAppearance when I was using a BackgroundImage and set the MouseOveBackColor to Transparent and never removed it

Removed it and it's now working a treat